# how to set pagination for joomla article groups?

Tags: joomla, pagination, article

I have a joomla based website. It has about 20 different topics. Every topic has about 10 articles.

How can I add pagination to every topic (front-end, not in the administration panel) to let my users navigate from one article to another article in the same topic?

I have attached an image that may help you exactly get my point:

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring a web-based content management system and doesn't contain a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by different topics you mean you have the articles in Categories, you can create a `Category Blog` menu item for each `Category`.

Then in the `Blog Layout Options` set `# Leading Articles` to 1, `# Intro Articles` to 0, `# Columns` to 1,  `Pagination` and `Pagination Results` to **Show**.

Depending on the version of Joomla you are using and the template involved you may have to fiddle around with `Read More...` settings for the menu item if your articles have `Read More` dividers in them.

Depending on your template and Joomla! version you may be able to add the pagination elements using an [Output Override](http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides) or there may even be an extension in [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org) that already does this.

Comment: tnx so much,cppl. it helped a lot.but i have one last question. the only problem is that i can't see other pages number (like the image i posted). there is only prev & next buttons. how can i set joomla to show articles by number, so i can choose from numbers...tnx again.

Comment: thnx cppl. it looks like you've been working on joomla for a long time. ;)

Comment: well, that really helped. now i have one final question plz. is there any way to add the ability for users to comment on the posts in blog mode? i mean, when i turn on blog mode as you said above, joomla doesn't show udjacomment anymore. and therefore users can't comment. is there any way to use comment ability on this mode? i will be thankful if you help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Actually I accidentally set all categories to unpublish even by default which was set. I set it back to publish and its working back as usual.